# Selenium actions - are they logged and where?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having some issues in finding Selenium logs of actions performed on the browser.

My situation is the following:

- I have a canvas with some clickable elements (it's a map).
- I click on a specific point through `actions.moveByOffset(pointToClick.getX(), pointToClick.getY()).click().build().perform()`. Sometimes the point gets clicked, sometimes it seems not and I need to figure out what exactly happens.

How can I make sure that the click has indeed been performed? I set up the `LoggingPreferences` in the WebDriver configuration class

```
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PROFILER, Level.ALL);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.ALL);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
logPrefs.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
```

but some of them (server, performance) are empty, while the browser logs contain data similar to what I see in the browser console. Since those are all the `LogType`s available, I'm not even sure I'm looking at the correct direction. Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few advanced libraries built-in to Selenium such as `EventFiringWebDriver`, `AbstractEventListener`, etc, which can be used to log all Selenium actions being performed.

Relevant Java Docs can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringDecorator.html
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverListener.html

I also have a working Python [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) example [from here](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_event_firing.py), which performs actions that get recorded and printed out. To run that example, you'll first need to `pip install seleniumbase`, then run the test with pytest: `pytest test_event_firing.py -s`.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import AbstractEventListener
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):
    def before_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        print("Before navigating to: %s" % url)

    def after_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        print("After navigating to: %s" % url)

    def before_find(self, by, value, driver):
        print('Before find "%s" (by = %s)' % (value, by))

    def after_find(self, by, value, driver):
        print('After find "%s" (by = %s)' % (value, by))

    def before_click(self, element, driver):
        print('Before clicking on element with text: "%s"' % element.text)

    def after_click(self, element, driver):
        print("Click complete!")

class EventFiringTests(BaseCase):
    def test_event_firing_webdriver(self):
        self.driver = EventFiringWebDriver(self.driver, MyListener())
        print("\n* EventFiringWebDriver example *")
        self.open("https://xkcd.com/1862/")
        self.click("link=About")
        self.open("https://store.xkcd.com/search")
        self.type('input[name="q"]', "xkcd book\n")
        self.open("https://xkcd.com/1822/")
```

The output of that prints the Selenium actions that were detected via the EventListener:

```
* EventFiringWebDriver example *
Before navigating to: https://xkcd.com/1862/
After navigating to: https://xkcd.com/1862/
Before find "About" (by = link text)
After find "About" (by = link text)
Before find "About" (by = link text)
After find "About" (by = link text)
Before clicking on element with text: "About"
Click complete!
Before navigating to: https://store.xkcd.com/search
After navigating to: https://store.xkcd.com/search
Before find "input[name="q"]" (by = css selector)
After find "input[name="q"]" (by = css selector)
Before navigating to: https://xkcd.com/1822/
After navigating to: https://xkcd.com/1822/
```

Similar solutions exist for the other Selenium language bindings.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your help. I implemented my EventFiringWebDriver with a WebDriverEventListener (I know it's deprecated but I cannot upgrade to Selenium 4). Unfortunately, I'm interacting with a canvas through the `Actions` class and click events are not fired (probably b/c I'm not dealing with `WebElement`s? IDK).

edit: sorry I really can't tag you

Comment: There's another way to detect if click events are being fired when going through the ``Actions`` class... You might be able to see if implementing the following gets you data:

``document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {console.log('Click was recorded!');});``

That would let you know if the browser detects any click actions at all. The best way would still be through built-in ``EventFiringWebDriver`` methods, but that might require setting up a different ``EventListener``.